# Rtabmap_ros with realsense odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_color_optical_frame

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, realsense, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use [RTABMAP_ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) with [realsense](http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense) as the RGB-D input.

Thanks to the useful tips from the post of http://answers.ros.org/question/218957/realsense-r200-with-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry/

I am able to see the data and get the rtabmap node running, but I am keep getting the warning of

```
[ WARN] [1452906467.763968588]: odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_color_optical_frame (stamp=1452906467.632809) after 0.100000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.100000)!
```

and no map was shown in the rtabmapviz.

command used:

roslaunch realsense realsense_r200_launch.launch dHeight:=240 dWidth:=320 dFPS:=30 cHeight:=240 cWidth:=320 cFPS:=30

roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw depth_registered_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info frame_id:=base_link rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" estimation:=1

My rqt_graph: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NR... Thank you very much !

The rosbag recorded are shared here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2puf8bD_Nz8RjdtQzlQUGhUNFk/view?usp=sharing
Does any body know the reason ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224250/rtabmap_ros-with-realsense-odometry:-could-not-get-transform-from-base_link-to-camera_color_optical_frame/) by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-15**:
Can you add the TF tree to your question?
`$ rosrun tf view_frames`
`$ evince frames.pdf`

**Comment by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on 2016-01-16**:
I don't have the right to attach, shared the frames.pdf in google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2puf8bD_Nz8R0RsdHB0MmlXdENmVFBPb3dkMnF5c0JzcFRN

Thank you very much !

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-16**:
The realsense_frame is not connected to TF tree. What is your launch file, or commands used? Normally, if you have RGB image + Registered depth image + RGB camera info topics and corresponding frames in TF, you should be good to map.

**Comment by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on 2016-01-17**:
I just attached the files I used, i thought I was following your advices in http://answers.ros.org/question/218957/realsense-r200-with-rtabmap-rgbd-odometry/
Thank you. Maybe I miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried the bag with your modified `rgbd_mapping.launch`. Did you record the bag with only `realsense_r200_launch.launch`? If yes, the realsense camera node publishes already transforms `/realsense_frame->/camera_depth_optical_frame` and `/realsense_frame->/camera_color_optical_frame`. The warning you are getting is because there are static_transform_publishers publishing also the same transforms when launching `rgbd_mapping.launch`.

Use this:

```
<!-- Frames: tf  -->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="base_to_realsense"
      args="0 0 0 -1.5707963 0 -1.5707963 /base_link /realsense_frame 100" />
```

instead of

```
<!-- Frames: tf  -->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"  name="base_to_color"
      args="0 0 0 -1.5707963 0 -1.5707963 /base_link /camera_color_optical_frame 100" /> 
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="color_to_depth"
      args="-0.1325 -0.1975 0.0 -1.570796327 0.0 0.0 /camera_color_optical_frame /camera_depth_optical_frame 100" />
```

So with your rosbag:

```
$ rosbag info 2016-01-18-16-14-41.bag
topics:      /camera/color/camera_info                  555 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo     
             /camera/color/image_raw/compressed         554 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth    555 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /tf                                       1110 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage
```

Launch the example like that:

```
$ roslaunch rgbd_mapping.launch rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw depth_registered_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info frame_id:=base_link rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" estimation:=1 compressed:=true
$ rosparam set use_sim_time true
$ rosbag play --clock 2016-01-18-16-14-41.bag
```

The warning may apppear on start 2-3 times but after it is ok:

```
[ INFO] [1453176055.454777214]: rtabmap 0.10.12 started...
[ WARN] [1453176067.382156280, 1453162481.896671693]: odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_color_optical_frame (stamp=1453162481.777381) after 0.100000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.100000)!
[ WARN] [1453176067.479223601, 1453162482.000379765]: odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_color_optical_frame (stamp=1453162481.886188) after 0.100000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.100000)!
[ INFO] [1453176067.531584531]: Odom: quality=0, std dev=1.000000m, update time=0.042757s
[ INFO] [1453176067.700283209]: Odom: quality=30, std dev=0.182574m, update time=0.141564s
[ INFO] [1453176067.835296760]: rtabmap: Rate=1.00s, Limit=0.000s, RTAB-Map=0.3025s, Pub=0.0020s (local map=1, WM=1)
[ INFO] [1453176067.874122050]: Odom: quality=65, std dev=0.124035m, update time=0.150594s
```

Here some screenshots:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on 2016-01-19**:
Yes, I recorded  the bag with only realsense_r200_launch, it is the default launch file of realsense_ros.

Thank you for your help. Your answer is very clear, thank you !

**Comment by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on 2016-01-20**:
Hi Mathieu, after following  your suggestion above, I still couldn' get the result,
Same warning appears.
The frame image is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2puf8bD_Nz8dW5CV3kwcTg1TG8/view?usp=sharing Seems map and odom haven't been linked.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-20**:
The /map and /odom frames will be published only if odometry is working. Doing it live, you should not use `compressed:=true` and `rosparam set use_sim_time true`. You can increase the wait time with argument `wait_for_transform:=1` for 1 sec instead of 0.1 sec.

**Comment by [sevense77](https://answers.ros.org/users/25628/sevense77/) on 2016-01-20**:
Thanks, Mathieu. Finally got the live version worked. RTABMAP is awesome. Seems the realsense_ros is not very stable though.

**Comment by [Gabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27669/gabee/) on 2016-08-03**:
Hey sevense77, how exactly did you get it to work? Because I tried the frame_id thing in the launch file but I am still getting "odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_depth_optical_frame (stamp=1452906467.632809) after 0.100000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.100000)!"

**Comment by [Gabee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27669/gabee/) on 2016-08-03**:
I am also getting the error :  "rtabmapviz: Could not get transform from odom to camera_link after 1.000000 seconds (for stamp=1470155388.571447)!" . Thanks for the help :)

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-08-03**:
Tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping has been updated for RealSense R200